# Inkscape to export png unicode characters doesnt seem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unicode, svg, kendo-ui, inkscape

i am trying to get Kendo Charts to png or pdf with Inkspace.

But i have a problem with Chart's Title. I am using Turkish characters and i can't show Turkish characters on title section. How can i solve this problem?

Thank you.

//here is the code:

```
   private const string INKSCAPE_PATH = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe";
        private const int WIDTH = 800;
        private const int HEIGHT = 600;


        private readonly Dictionary<KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat, string> MimeTypes = new Dictionary<KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat, string>
        {
            { KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat.PNG, "image/png" },
            { KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat.PDF, "application/pdf" }
        };



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _Export(string svg, KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat format)
        {

            var svgText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(svg);
            var svgFile = TempFileName() + ".svg";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(svgFile, svgText);

            var outFile = DoExport(svgFile, format);
            var attachment = "export" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(outFile);

            return File(outFile, MimeTypes[format], attachment);
        }

        private string DoExport(string svgFile, KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat format)
        {

            var extension = format == KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat.PNG ? "png" : "pdf";
            var outFile = TempFileName() + "." + extension;
            var inkscape = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            inkscape.StartInfo.FileName = INKSCAPE_PATH;
            inkscape.StartInfo.Arguments =
                String.Format("--file \"{0}\" --export-{1} \"{2}\" --export-width {3} --export-height {4}",
                              svgFile, extension, outFile, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            inkscape.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            inkscape.Start();

            inkscape.WaitForExit();

            return outFile;
        }

        private string TempFileName()
        {
            return System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName());
        }


        #endregion


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, change _export action;

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _Export(string svg, KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat format)
        {
            var abc = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
            svg = svg.Replace("%F6", "ö");
            svg = svg.Replace("%D6", "Ö");

            svg = svg.Replace("%C7", "Ç");
            svg = svg.Replace("%E7", "ç");

            svg = svg.Replace("%DC", "Ü");
            svg = svg.Replace("%FC", "ü");

            svg = svg.Replace("F0", "ğ");
            svg = svg.Replace("D0", "Ğ");

            svg = svg.Replace("DD", "İ");
            svg = svg.Replace("%FD", "ı");

            var svgText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(svg, abc);
            var svgFile = TempFileName() + ".svg";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(svgFile, svgText);

            var outFile = DoExport(svgFile, format);
            var attachment = "export" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(outFile);

            return File(outFile, MimeTypes[format], attachment);
        }
```